# GridView в ViewPager

Tags: android

Не могу запустить GridView в ViewPager. Картинки для GridView берутся из папки на SD. Приложение запускается, но на странице где должен быть GridView ничего нет. В логах видно что даже адаптер для GridView не запускается. Пример кода для GridView(ниже) в отдельном приложении работает.  Где я туплю?

код фрагмента с гридвью:

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

private Context context;
GridView mGrid;
private static final String TAG = "myLogs";

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Log.i(TAG,"onCreat first");

    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "ICOIN/");
    File[] filesArray = dir.listFiles();
    if (filesArray != null) {
        Adapter adapter = new AdapterGridView(getActivity(),filesArray);
        Log.i(TAG,"adapter");
        mGrid.setAdapter((ListAdapter) adapter);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //задаем разметку фрагменту
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_first_fragment, container, false);
    Log.i(TAG,"viewFirst");
    //ну и контекст, так как фрагменты не содержат собственного
    context = view.getContext();
    mGrid = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    return view;
}
```

код адаптера гридвью:

```
public class AdapterGridView extends ArrayAdapter<File> {

LayoutInflater mInflater;
Picasso mPicasso;
private static final String TAG = "myLogs";

public AdapterGridView(Context context, File[] objects) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item, objects);
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    mPicasso = Picasso.with(context);
}

@Override
public View getView ( final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        Log.i(TAG,"adapter grid");
    }
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    mPicasso.load(getItem(position)).fit().centerCrop().into(imageView);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(getItem(position)));
            getContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""));
         }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Comment: onCreate ведь вызывается раньше, чем onCreateView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых забыл предоставить приложению права на чтение sd-карты, бывает)
Во-вторых как сказал metalurgus "onCreate ведь вызывается раньше, чем onCreateView?" необходимо весь код из onCreat перенести в OnCreatView